# The problem changed, now the array mixes up the data

Tags: java

When I try to show in output the titles of my books (getBooksByAuthor=`getLibriByAutore`) the output is completely different, the array is mixing up the data: [photo of the problem](http://prntscr.com/mke4fv) (in debugging mode with variables), in the main the data also mixes up a little [MAIN](http://prntscr.com/mke6qb). I inserted the "p" and the "b" but not in only one author (it has to be by author), there are 4 classes, the most important are the main and the "Editore" class which has the getBy... method.

CLASS EDITORE:

```
class Editore {
    private String nome;
    private Libro[] libri;
    protected int k=0;//scorri

    public Editore(){} 

    public Editore(String nome, Libro[] libri){

        this.nome=nome;
        this.libri=libri;
    }

    public String getNome(){
        return this.nome;
    }

    public Libro[] getLibri(){
        return this.libri;
    }

    public void setNome(String n){
        this.nome=n;
    }

    public void setLibri(Libro[] l){
        this.libri=l;
    }

    public Libro[] getLibriByAutore(Libro[] e,String n, String c){
        Libro[] ris;
        ris = new Libro[libri.length];
        for(int i=0; i<libri.length; i++){
            if(e[i].getAutore().getNome().equals(n)&&e[i].getAutore().getCognome().equals(c)){
                System.out.println("Titolo libro n"+i+": "+e[i].getTitolo());
                k++;
            }
        }
        return ris;
    }
}
```

MAIN CLASS:

```
public class Libreria {
    public static void main(String[]arg){
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));

        String nome="", cognome="", periodo="", titolo="", nomenew="", cognomenew="", editore="";
        int annoLibro=0, giorno, mese, anno;
        Calendar data=Calendar.getInstance();
        Autore a= new Autore();
        Libro l = new Libro();
        Editore e= new Editore();
        Libro[] libri= new Libro[3];

        System.out.print("Inserisci il nome dell' editore: ");
            try{
                editore=br.readLine();
            }catch(Exception ex){
                System.err.println("ERRORE");
            }
            e.setNome(editore);

        for(int j=0; j<3; j++){
            System.out.print("Inserisci il titolo del libro: ");
            try{
                titolo= br.readLine();
            }catch(Exception ex){
                System.err.println("ERRORE");
            }
            libri[j]=new Libro();
            libri[j].setTitolo(titolo);
            l.setTitolo(titolo);

            System.out.print("Inserisci l' anno del libro: ");
            try{
                annoLibro= Integer.valueOf(br.readLine());
            }catch(Exception ex){
                System.err.println("ERRORE");
            }
            libri[j].setAnno(annoLibro);
            l.setAnno(annoLibro);

            System.out.print("Inserisci il nome dell' autore: ");
            try{
                nome= br.readLine();
            }catch(Exception ex){
                System.err.println("ERRORE");
            }
            a.setNome(nome);

            System.out.print("Inserisci il cognome dell' autore: ");
            try{
                cognome= br.readLine();
            }catch(Exception ex){
                System.err.println("ERRORE");
            }
            a.setCognome(cognome);
            System.out.print("Inserisci il periodo dell' autore: ");
            try{
                periodo= br.readLine();
            }catch(Exception ex){
                System.err.println("ERRORE");
            }
            a.setPeriodo(periodo);
            try{
                System.out.print("Inserisci il giorno di nascita dell' autore: ");
                giorno= Integer.valueOf(br.readLine());
                System.out.print("Inserisci il mese di nascita dell' autore: ");
                mese= Integer.valueOf(br.readLine());
                System.out.print("Inserisci l' anno di nascita dell' autore: ");
                anno= Integer.valueOf(br.readLine());
                data.set(anno, mese, giorno);
                a.setData(data);
            }catch(Exception ex){
                System.err.println("ERRORE");
            }
            libri[j].setAutore(a);
            l.setAutore(a);
            System.out.println("AUTORE SUCCESSIVO");
            e= new Editore(editore, libri);
            a = new Autore(nome, cognome, periodo, data);
            libri[j]= new Libro(titolo, a, annoLibro);
        }
        System.out.println("Di quale autore vuoi stampare i libri? (nome,cognome)");
        try{
            nomenew=br.readLine();
            cognomenew=br.readLine();
            }catch(Exception ex){
                System.err.println("ERRORE");
            }
        a.setNome(nomenew);
        a.setCognome(cognomenew);
        //String ris[]=new String[libri.length];
        System.out.println("Libri:");

        for(int kk=0; kk<libri.length; kk++){

            e.getLibriByAutore(libri, nomenew, cognomenew);
        }

    }
}
```

The other 2 classes are: Autore [Author (of the books)] and Libro (Books), Autore has only `getNome()` = getName(), `getCognome()` = getSurname(), `getPeriodo()` = getPeriod(), `getData()` = getDate() [the sets are the same]. Libro has `getTitolo()` = getTitle(), `getAutore()` = getAuthor() and `getAnno()` = getYear() [the sets are also the same here].

Comment: Just to make sure, when you do `ris = new Libro[ks];` in your `public Libro[] getLibriByAutore(Libro[] e,String n, String c)`, as you declared `ks = 0`, your array's size is 0. I think that may be the problem.

Comment: thanks for the answer, it worked in part, now the numbers are completely random (I updated the post)

Comment: I suggest you to run your program in debug mode and check manually every assignment of values. Its the fastest way to find where your bug is.

Comment: thanks for the suggestion, I updated the question and now I am more confused 

Comment: can you give me your full code? So I can test it. send a link or post your full code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well I managed to emulate your code. The problem is that you were replicating a lot of instances of the same objects, overwriting info again and again. Example:

```
for(int j=0; j<3; j++){
        System.out.print("Inserisci il titolo del libro: ");
        try{
            titolo= br.readLine();
        }catch(Exception ex){
            System.err.println("ERRORE");
        }
        libri[j]=new Libro();
        libri[j].setTitolo(titolo);
        l.setTitolo(titolo); // This is no sense, you created a Libro in the previous lines
```

Also, I recommend you to use an `ArrayList` of objects instead an `Array` of objects. With `ArrayList` is so much easy to add, read and delete objects, because it has methods to do it, like `.add()`. I modified your code and fixed it using `ArrayList`.

If you have any doubts about the code, feel free to ask.

```
public class Libreria {
public static void main(String[]arg){
    BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));

    String nome="", cognome="", periodo="", titolo="", nomenew="", cognomenew="", editore="";
    int annoLibro=0, giorno, mese, anno;
    Calendar data=Calendar.getInstance();
    ArrayList<Libro> libri = new ArrayList<Libro>(); 
    Editore e= new Editore();

    System.out.print("Inserisci il nome dell' editore: ");
        try{
            editore=br.readLine();
        }catch(Exception ex){
            System.err.println("ERRORE");
        }

        for(int j=0; j<2; j++){

        Autore a= new Autore();
        Libro l = new Libro();

        System.out.print("Inserisci il titolo del libro: ");
        try{
            titolo= br.readLine();
        }catch(Exception ex){
            System.err.println("ERRORE");
        }

        System.out.print("Inserisci l' anno del libro: ");
        try{
            annoLibro= Integer.valueOf(br.readLine());
        }catch(Exception ex){
            System.err.println("ERRORE");
        }

        System.out.print("Inserisci il nome dell' autore: ");
        try{
            nome= br.readLine();
        }catch(Exception ex){
            System.err.println("ERRORE");
        }

        System.out.print("Inserisci il cognome dell' autore: ");
        try{
            cognome= br.readLine();
        }catch(Exception ex){
            System.err.println("ERRORE");
        }
        a.setCognome(cognome);
        System.out.print("Inserisci il periodo dell' autore: ");
        try{
            periodo= br.readLine();
        }catch(Exception ex){
            System.err.println("ERRORE");
        }
        a.setPeriodo(periodo);
        try{
            System.out.print("Inserisci il giorno di nascita dell' autore: ");
            giorno= Integer.valueOf(br.readLine());
            System.out.print("Inserisci il mese di nascita dell' autore: ");
            mese= Integer.valueOf(br.readLine());
            System.out.print("Inserisci l' anno di nascita dell' autore: ");
            anno= Integer.valueOf(br.readLine());
            data.set(anno, mese, giorno);

        }catch(Exception ex){
            System.err.println("ERRORE");
        }

        a = new Autore(nome, cognome, periodo, data);
        l = new Libro(titolo, a, annoLibro);
        libri.add(l);

        System.out.println("Autore is " + a.getNome());
        System.out.println("Libro is " + l.getTitolo());

        System.out.println("AUTORE SUCCESSIVO");     
    }

    e= new Editore(editore, libri);
    System.out.println("Editore is " + e.getNome());


    System.out.println("Di quale autore vuoi stampare i libri? (nome then cognome)");
    Autore b = new Autore();
    try{
        nomenew=br.readLine();
        cognomenew=br.readLine();
        }catch(Exception ex){
            System.err.println("ERRORE");
        }
    b.setNome(nomenew);
    b.setCognome(cognomenew);
    ArrayList<Libro> finalList = e.getLibriByAutore(libri, nomenew, cognomenew);

    if(!finalList.isEmpty()) {
        for(Libro libro : finalList) {
            System.out.println("Libri : " + libro.getTitolo());
        }

    } else {
        System.out.println("Not found!");
    }



}
}
```

Autore class:

```
public class Autore {

private String nome;
private String cognome;
private String periodo;
private Calendar data;

public Autore(String nome, String cognome, String periodo, Calendar data) {
    // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    this.nome = nome;
    this.cognome = cognome;
    this.periodo = periodo;
    this.data = data;
}

public Autore() {
    // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
}


public String getNome() {
    return nome;
}

public void setNome(String nome) {
    this.nome = nome;
}

public String getCognome() {
    return cognome;
}

public void setCognome(String cognome) {
    this.cognome = cognome;
}

public String getPeriodo() {
    return periodo;
}

public void setPeriodo(String periodo) {
    this.periodo = periodo;
}

public Calendar getData() {
    return data;
}

public void setData(Calendar data) {
    this.data = data;
}



}
```

Libro class:

```
public class Libro {

private String titolo;
private Autore a;
private int annoLibro;

public Libro(String titolo, Autore a, int annoLibro) {
    this.titolo = titolo;
    this.a = a;
    this.annoLibro = annoLibro;
}

public Libro() {
    // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
}

public String getTitolo() {
    return titolo;
}

public void setTitolo(String titolo) {
    this.titolo = titolo;
}

public Autore getAutore() {
    return a;
}

public void setAutore(Autore a) {
    this.a = a;
}

public int getAnno() {
    return annoLibro;
}

public void setAnno(int annoLibro) {
    this.annoLibro = annoLibro;
}


}
```

Editore class:

```
class Editore {
private String nome;
private ArrayList<Libro> libri;
protected int k=0;//scorri

public Editore(){} 

public Editore(String nome, ArrayList<Libro> libri){
    this.nome=nome;
    this.libri=libri;
}

public String getNome(){
    return this.nome;
}

public ArrayList<Libro> getLibri(){
    return this.libri;
}

public void setNome(String n){
    this.nome=n;
}

public void setLibri(ArrayList<Libro> l){
    this.libri=l;
}

public ArrayList<Libro> getLibriByAutore(ArrayList<Libro> e,String n, String c){
    ArrayList<Libro> list = new ArrayList<Libro>();
    for(Libro p : e){
        if(p.getAutore().getNome().equals(n) && p.getAutore().getCognome().equals(c)){
            list.add(p);
        }
    }
    return list;
}

}
```

[image: result]

Comment: Does the `ArrayList` work in NetBeans IDE 8.1? Because I can only use this for java

Comment: Yes it works just use the appropiate `import java.util.ArrayList` or something like that. Dont forget to mark my answer as correct if it helped you!

Comment: I have modified the code a lot in these 5 hours, there were a lot of errors but now it works without ArrayList, but you helped me with a lot of errors, thanks. Basically here: 
`System.out.println("Inse...);
    try{
        nomenew=br.readLine();
        cognomenew=br.readLine();
        }catch(Exception ex){
            System.err.println("ERRORE");
        }
    b.setNome(nomenew);
    b.setCognome(cognomenew); `

I was setting the name and the surname, which is an error. and the other 
fundamental error was in the main class, the e.getLibriByAutore without System.out.println().